# can I change the Window system format via python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have a program that is using `.` as decimal symbol. But my friend in Vietnam uses `,` as decimal symbol. Is there a way to change that using a python script?
Edit 1: I'm talking about system wide. I need a python script that autochange system decimalsymbol to the dot '.'. Thank @CristiFati

Comment: Put in the entire code as string and switch "." with "," (for example using `string.replace('.', ',')`). To prevent changing dots in methods, just check if the characters to the left and right of the dot are numbers.

Comment: Are you talking system wide? like number formats from Regional settings?

Comment: Or, possibly, changing your friend's behavior through a Python script?

Comment: The initial numeric locale is the C (POSIX) locale. You can change it to the user's configured default at startup, e.g. `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')`, or specifically to Vietnam, e.g. `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'Vietnamese_Vietnam')`. Then you can format numbers with "," for the decimal point and "." as the thousands separator, e.g. `locale.format('%0.2f', 1000.50, grouping=True)` should return `'1.000,50'`.

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, i am. Thank you!

Comment: @eryksun How can i do that with python? thank you

Comment: My examples are in Python, but just to change the locale for the current process, not the whole system. I don't recommend doing the latter at all. The user can easily change the locale settings. Programs shouldn't be messing with this.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you! But my friends don't know about windows. They can't change any system setting.

Comment: A Python script that uses `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')` will change the locale for the Python process to whatever is configured for the current user. A user that's comfortable with Vietnamese conventions should configure Windows as such, and almost certainly someone *in Vietnam* will have Windows configured that way already.

Comment: @eryksun thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm done with Googling. Just using registry and set decimal value.